# Not submitting to database but shows success message

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if ($stmt = $dbconn->prepare('INSERT INTO `astm_clients_tbl` (`u_name`, `u_email`, `u_password`, `u_plain_password`, `u_phone`, `u_referral_id`, `u_referrer`, `u_join_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $auth_name, $to, $password, $plainPass, $tel, $ref_id, $ref, $join_date);
    $stmt->execute();
    header('Location: register.php?msg=success');
    exit();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    header('Location: register.php?msg=error');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Do **NOT** store plain password in db please

Comment: You should check the result of `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: `$stmt->close()` will never be executed, since `exit()` ends the script.

Comment: You should log the reason for the error so you can troubleshoot it. `error_log($dbconn->error);`

Answer (score -2):

`$stmt->execute()` returns bool. Check if it's `True` before redirecting.

Take a cue below

```
if ($stmt = $dbconn->prepare('INSERT INTO `astm_clients_tbl` (`u_name`, `u_email`, `u_password`, `u_plain_password`, `u_phone`, `u_referral_id`, `u_referrer`, `u_join_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $auth_name, $to, $password, $plainPass, $tel, $ref_id, $ref, $join_date);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: register.php?msg=success');
        exit();
        $stmt->close();
    }
} else {
    header('Location: register.php?msg=error');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to check each method call for errors manually. Instead enable mysqli error reporting.

Comment: @ForALLs . It actually produced a FALSE

Comment: header('Location: register.php?msg=error'); is extremely unhelpful and practically useless